# Magento soap API for Tax

Tags: magento-1.8, api, tax, soap

**Is there a way to retrieve the tax rules in magento via soap?**

If is not possible I think to create a csv with the Tax rates and **upload with the import**, but in **automatic way**... is it possible?

Someone has already done something similar?

Moreover I need to do it into a project in vb.net. but if someone has done something similar in php or other languages it can be usefull anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are many ext available for tax rates via API on Magento Connect

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sales-tax-extension-for-avalara-s-avatax.html

You can set table rates in Magento but there is not "Public" API for taxes available.

Comment: I can't use ext because the company that manage magento and me are two different companies. We have the db with data and our client would like to put them into magento. So the only way is through api.
But I have no idea how to do that for Tax Rates

Comment: Are there so many changes in tax rules and rates that you need to frequently set it via API? Otherwise it would be better to talk to the company and tell them how to set it up.